# Store xml values in arraylist in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, arraylist, xml-parsing

I have a xml as follows need to store the values of xml field in the array list can anybody help.

```
<Search>
<Fields>
<Field>
<IndexId>241</IndexId><IndexName>ProductCode</IndexName><IndexType>S</IndexType><IndexLength>100</IndexLength><IndexFlag>D</IndexFlag><UsefulInfoFlag>N</UsefulInfoFlag><UsefulInfosize>255</UsefulInfosize><IndexAttribute>0</IndexAttribute></Field>
<Field>
<IndexId>263</IndexId><IndexName>Partner Name</IndexName><IndexType>S</IndexType><IndexLength>100</IndexLength><IndexFlag>D</IndexFlag><UsefulInfoFlag>N</UsefulInfoFlag><UsefulInfosize>255</UsefulInfosize><IndexAttribute>0</IndexAttribute></Field>
<Field>
<IndexId>420</IndexId><IndexName>Day</IndexName><IndexType>S</IndexType><IndexLength>100</IndexLength><IndexFlag>D</IndexFlag><UsefulInfoFlag>N</UsefulInfoFlag><UsefulInfosize>255</UsefulInfosize><IndexAttribute>0</IndexAttribute></Field>
<Field>
<IndexId>421</IndexId><IndexName>Month</IndexName><IndexType>S</IndexType><IndexLength>100</IndexLength><IndexFlag>D</IndexFlag><UsefulInfoFlag>N</UsefulInfoFlag><UsefulInfosize>255</UsefulInfosize><IndexAttribute>0</IndexAttribute></Field>
</Fields>
</Search>
```

Comment: Use JAX-B or JAX-P create a class that resembles your xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is various Parser library you can use.
reference link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java_xml/java_xml_parsers.htm

Here you go with one for them

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;


File inputFile = new File("input.txt");

DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Field");

for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
    System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("IndexId"));
    System.out.println(eElement.getAttribute("IndexName"));
}
```